# What colour would a flat world's sky be?

Tags: science-based, sunlight, nonspherical-worlds

In continuation of my [previous question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/156755/penumbra-colors-of-a-flat-earths-sun-shades), I'm wondering about the colour of a flat world's sky.

To recap the previous question, I'm imagining a flat world with the sun fixed relatively low above the center, with a number of large "sky island" type shades orbiting it to produce the day-night cycle. Here's a mockup map:

[image: UN emblem with a sun and one shade on top]

So, I'm wondering if the sky would necessarily be blue in this world, Rayleigh scattering being what it is. Further, would North America have a different colored sky than, say, the Wreath Peninsula? How much does it matter whether and how far the sun is inside or outside the atmo-layer?

Comment: Can you be more specific than `the sun fixed relatively low above the center`?  It makes a big difference whether the "sun" is below the upper limit of the atmosphere or not.

Comment: @cowlinator I'm currently leaving it open whether the sun is inside the atmosphere or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sky would range from reds nearest the sun’s periphery to blues as you look further from the sun then farthest edges of the sky should look violet.  As you stated it will be because of Rayleigh scattering.